# Proper use of volatile keyword in C

Tags: c, volatile

I am a beginner with C and i came across to the following code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

unsigned int ReturnSquare(void);

int main(void) {

int k;
int *mPtr;

mPtr = (int*) 0x1234;

*mPtr = 10;

 k = (int) ReturnSquare();

 printf("%p --> %d\n",mPtr,k);

}

unsigned int ReturnSquare(void)
{
  unsigned  volatile int a = * (unsigned volatile int *) 0x1234;
  unsigned  volatile int b = * (unsigned volatile int *) 0x1234;
  return a * b;
}
```

Could you please help me understand what is the use of volatile in this code?

It seems that the program does not work correctly. Any suggestion and explanation is very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are writing 10 in address 0x1234 and then you calculate content at this address times content of the address (it's not necessary to  get  10*10). ```volatile``` means 'no optimization' i.e. that the value should be read every time and keeping it in temporary place like register is not allowed

Comment: This is some b0rken program from the DOS era or something. If you're a beginner, the best thing you can do with this program is to delete it and forget it existed.

Comment: You should tell us what the program is supposed to do. Where exactly did you find this code? On which platform is it supposed to run? Reading from address `0x1234` looks totally bogous to me.

Comment: "Not working properly" is a different issue than the use of `volatile` - what do you expect it to do, and how does it not work.  It appears that this is likely hypothetical example code for an embedded system rather than real code expected to run on a real target.  It is squaring the value at address 0x1234, which is unlikely to represent a real address, and in practice would probably represent some external input hardware on a GPIO port for example.  If run on a modern desktop OS, I would expect it to seg-fault on access to an invalid address.

Comment: Although external I/O should be accessed as volatile, if the purpose is to _square_ the input value, you do not want to make two separate reads in any case, as the value may change between assignment of `a` and `b`.  Rather you want to return `a * a` and remove `b` altogether.  In that sense this code is broken.

Comment: On volatile: https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword

Comment: As a beginner, be wary of code you just "came across"; not all code is good code, and you need to know what the author was trying to achieve or demonstrate to understand its purpose.  By any measure this is particularly bizarre code - choose your sources carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the same register twice the compiler can decide to optimize the behaviour.

It could turn the code into something like this:

```
unsigned  int a = * (unsigned int *) 0x1234;
unsigned  int b = a;
```

When you add volatile the compiler will make no assumption on the second read that the value will be the same and it will generate the extra instructions for dereferencing the pointer to register again.

It might be too advanced for you right now but you can check this with the assembly output option on your compiler, the volatile version will have more assembly instructions.

Comment: thank you for your answer. How could we modify it to run properly?

Comment: writing to adresses directly is not permitted on all major operating systems, so if you use one of those you cant make it run properly like this.

Comment: What you can do is create a global variable and replace 0x1234 with its address, but that really is another question. Better that you learn about variables and their addresses first

Answer (score 2):

It forces the compiler to read the referenced value every time it is used. Compiler knows that this object can be changed by something not seen by the compiler in the normal program execution path.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show is a bad example of what `volatile` does, and a bad example for C code in general.

First, then the code does this:

```
mPtr = (int*) 0x1234;
*mPtr = 10;
```

it takes a seemingly arbitrary address, `0x1234`, and puts an `int` value there. In general, you cannot know you are allowed to write to this address. It might not be mapped in your virtual address space, and, if it is, there might be something important there, and writing over it will break a program. So this program is doing something bad and unsupported, and we should not expect it will work. (In special environments, it is possible the layout of the memory address space is specified and can be used in ways like this. Such situations should always be clearly documented, and the code is limited to the specific systems it was designed for; it is not suitable for use as general-purpose C code.)

Second, the code does nothing special that shows any difference between objects with and without `volatile`. Aside from the mistake that it writes to `0x1234` using `int` and reads from it using `unsigned int`, normal execution of this code is going to produce an unsurprising result, 100, if the program does not crash due to using `0x1234`. A better example would be a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1234;
    volatile int b = 5678;
    printf("Press enter to proceed.\n");
    getchar();
    printf("a = %d.\n", a);
    printf("b = %d.\n", b);
}
```

Students would then be instructed to compile this program with optimization and debugging enabled, run it in a debugger, interrupt it (in the debugger) while the program is waiting for input, use the debugger to change the values of `a` and `b`, and then continue running the program. The result would be that the program displays `a` with its original value, 1234, but displays `b` with its changed value. (In fact, due to optimization, `a` might not exist in a way that can be changed by the debugger.)

This would demonstrate that a compiler assumes it has full control over non-volatile objects such as `a`, so it may optimize code in ways that assume they do not change unexpectedly, but the compiler does not make such assumptions with `volatile` objects. With a `volatile` object, the compiler reloads it from memory each time it is used in source code (and it writes it to memory each time it is modified in source code).

The meaning of `volatile` is that an object may change in ways not normally known to the compiler. Therefore, demonstrating how volatile works requires modifying the program from outside the program. Although the debugger is one way to accomplish this, an intended use of `volatile` is to access locations in the address space that are connected to I/O devices instead of normal memory. These locations may change when some input/output operation occurs. The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler not to treat objects as normal memory, to expect that they may change unexpectedly from external actions.